# how to add UIImage from a NSMutableArray of images to UIButton using setImage

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uibutton, nsmutablearray

I have an array of UIImages which I have created like this

```
UIImage *tButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button-measurement.png"];
UIImage *tPButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button-parts.png"];
UIImage *oPButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button-onboard.png"];
UIImage *dButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button-opening.png"];
```

// then depending on the corresponding values of a NSDicitonary / keyvalue pairs will decide which UIImages will be put into my array like so

```
NSMutableArray *arrayOfButtonImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

if ([hasInfoSetIDString isEqualToString:@"T"]) {
    [arrayOfButtonImages addObject:tButtonImage];
}
if ([hasTSetIDString isEqualToString:@"T"]) {
    [arrayOfButtonImages addObject:tPButtonImage];
}
if ([hasOSetIDString isEqualToString:@"T"]) {
    [arrayOfButtonImages addObject:oPButtonImage];
}
if ([hasDSetIDString isEqualToString:@"T"]) {
    [arrayOfButtonImages addObject:dButtonImage];
}
```

by this point depending on the values in my NSDictionary I might have an array that looks something like this.

```
NSLog(@"%@", arrayOfButtonImages);

(
    "<UIImage: 0x2001f4c0>",
    "<UIImage: 0x1ed51c20>"
)
```

I then try to apply those images to the buttons I have, so the buttons are "dynamic" per say.

```
if (arrayOfButtonImages != nil) {

            for (int i = 0; i < [arrayOfButtonImages count]; i++) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    [jumpButton1P setImage:[arrayOfButtonImages objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                }
                else if (i == 1) {
                    [jumpButton2P setImage:[arrayOfButtonImages objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                }
                else if (i == 2) {
                    [jumpButton3P setImage:[arrayOfButtonImages objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                }
                else if (i == 3) {
                    [jumpButton4P setImage:[arrayOfButtonImages objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                }
                else if (i == 4) {
                    [jumpButton5P setImage:[arrayOfButtonImages objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                }
            }
}
```

so after all that is said and done, the image is not appearing on my UIButton.. I have checked to make sure that the UIButton variable is connected with the UIBUtton object in Interface Builder.. but still something is going wrong.

I have even just tried a simple

```
UIImage *btnImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"diagram-P.png"];
[jumpButton1P setImage:btnImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

and this dosnt even work.

hopefully this all makes sense.. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So I am loading the UIButtons on a UISubView which is what is causing me the trouble.. I am trying to figure out when is the best time to call the images to get this to work. If i assign a basic image to the UIButton in viewDidLoad it works perfectly.. but the catch is I Have to wait for the informaiton of my NSDictionary which is after the mainview is loaded and hence causing the troubles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the backgroundImage instead:

```
[jumpButton1P setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"diagram-P"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: bugger.. just tried that and thats not working either... painful.

Comment: try leaving the image blank inside of interface builder, and just set the backgroundImage whenever you need it inside of the code

Comment: thats what I am doing if you look at it inside IB you cannot see the UIButton unless you select it with the mouse.

Answer (score 0):

Test it again after setting the button type = "Custom" in Interface Builder or manually:

```
  UIButton *btnOne = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
```

And then call setImage or setBackgroundImage

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Not to sound redundant, but have you confirmed that the image objects are indeed linked to your project? Press on your project in the Project Navigator, select your app target, press on the Build Phases tab, and expand the "Copy Bundle Resources (x items)" section.

Also, make sure that all of your images are listed there and the filepath next to the items are correct (pointing to your project, not your desktop/pictures folder or something).

Comment: yep those images are there and working. I found out if I just apply the image to the button in the viewdidload it works perfectly. I think its a timing issue in the current method that I am doing it in.. effectively I am getting the NSDictionary i use to make my decisions back after the main UIView has loaded i then i call the method where i pass the images to the correct buttons which are displayed on a subview... something in the way I am doing this is causing the problem